# How to split text only by one dot, but not by triple dots?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this text:

```
const text = "If you look at a map of Europe... you will... notice. That apart from the big... landmass known as the continent, there are two small islands to the west."
```

And I need to split it by a dot (and keep the dot in the sentence), but I only need to split it by one dot, so I want the following array as a result:

```
const result = [
 "If you look at a map of Europe... you will... notice.",
 "That apart from the big... landmass known as the continent, there are two small islands to the west."
]
```

I have already created a function that can split sentences by a dot, question mark, and exclamation mark, but it doesn't work properly when there are triple dots in the sentence.

```
function splitByPunctuationMark(str) {
 return str.split(/(?<=[!.?])/).map(value => value.trim())
}
```

**UPDATED**

`splitByPunctuationMark()` gives me the following result:

#1 When there are no triple dots in the source text

```
const result = splitByPunctuationMark("If you look at a map of Europe you will notice. That apart from the big landmass known as the continent, there are two small islands to the west.")

console.log(result)
/*
[
 "If you look at a map of Europe you will notice.", 
 "That apart from the big landmass known as the continent, there are two small islands to the west."
]
*/
```

#2 When there are triple dots in the source text

```
const result = splitByPunctuationMark("If you look at a map of Europe... you will... notice. That apart from the big... landmass known as the continent, there are two small islands to the west.")

console.log(result)
/*
[
 "If you look at a map of Europe.", 
 ".", 
 ".", 
 "you will.", 
 ".", 
 ".", 
 "notice.", 
 "That apart from the big.", 
 ".", 
 ".", 
 "landmass known as the continent, there are two small islands to the west."
]
*/
```

Comment: Please always tag with the language like I just did (as regex-flavor can be different). What was your output that "doesn't work properly"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it. At first I make all "..." disappear by converting them to a separator string. This string needs to be chosen carefully, so it won't be found anywhere in the target string. After splitting at the remaining single "." I then replace the "..." back into their original positions.

```js
const text = "If you look at a map of Europe... you will... notice. That apart from the big... landmass known as the continent, there are two small islands to the west.And here is a third ... is it a sentence?   And a forth!"


const sep="@threedots@",res=text.replaceAll("...",sep).split(/(?<=[.!?])\s*/).map(e=>e.replaceAll(sep,"..."));

console.log(res);
```

In order to preserve the "." at the end of each sentence I used a lookbehind in the regular expression: `/(?<=[.!?])\s*/`. This will consider 0...n whitespace characters as separator patterns, if they occur immediately after a ".", an "!" or after a "?".

@Martin Niederl quite rightly remarked about the possibility of *any number* of repeated dots occuring. He presented a solution which I also consider helpful. Here is my take on it (allowing also for other end-of-sentence characters):

```js
const text = "If you look at a map of Europe..... you will... notice. That apart from the big.. landmass known as the continent, there are two small islands to the west.And here is a third .... Is it a sentence?   And a forth!"
const res=text.split(/(?<=(?<!\.)[.!?](?!\.))\s*/);
console.log(res);
```

I now have a positive lookbehind that contains a pattern consisting of a negative lookbehind of a ".", followed by exactly one of the characters ".", "!" or "?" and another negative lookahead of another ".". Immediately after the positive lookbehind I demand a sequence of 0 to any number of whitespace characters.

Comment: Only bug -- he wanted the "." to remain at the end of the string.

Comment: I do not know if it is a problem for the questioner, but the solution does not deal with e.g. 2 or 4 dots.

Answer (score 2):

`/(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)/` matches only individual dots.
You could then split it based on that, remove empty sentences, trim the sentences and reapply the stripped dot:

```js
const text = "If you look at a map of Europe... you will... notice. That apart from the big... landmass known as the continent, there are two small islands to the west."

let sentences = text.split(/(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)/)
                    .filter(sentence => sentence.length > 0)
                    .map(sentence => sentence.trim() + ".")
                    
console.log(sentences)
```

Comment: Good point about the other numbers of repeated dots (+1)! I have taken up your idea.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
(.*\w\.\s)|(.*\w\.)
```

(.*\w.\s) - matches any string ending with a letter followed by a dot followed by a space.

OR

(.*\w.) - matches any string ending with a letter followed by a dot.

https://regex101.com/r/pk68Ix/1

Comment: This solution is very unrobust, only a maximum of 2 " sentences" are matched. For example, if "abc. abc" is appended to the text from the question, there is only one match for the entire text except for the "abc" at the very end. https://regex101.com/r/5vDDiW/1